# Why is my rails application not responding properly to the .js format in production environement?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery, render

i have a very simple rails application that is ajax-based for some of it's functionality.
When i'm using it from a development environment, everything runs as expected.
However, something weird happens in production environment: when an ajax call is being made, the HTML (HAML based) layouts are being rendered instead of the js (Coffee based).

When comparing the logs from production and development, it's obvious that there is something i'm doing wrong in the way the responses are handled, but i've been scratching my head for hours now without a clue.

Let's say my request is: /software_tags/1/edit.js
On my development logs, i can see (And the output is right, i get the expected javascript page):

```
Started GET "/software_tags/1/edit.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-17 16:59:34 -0700
Processing by SoftwareTagsController#edit as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.haml (0.1ms)
  Rendered software_tags/_form.haml (4.5ms)
  Rendered software_tags/edit.js.coffee (5.7ms) <---- THIS IS GOOD!
Completed 200 OK in 10ms (Views: 8.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

On my development logs however, i see (And the output is wrong, i get the HTML page):

```
Started GET "/software_tags/1/edit.js" for x.x.x.x at 2012-07-18 01:59:54 +0200
Processing by SoftwareTagsController#edit as JS <--- Wouldn't that force the edit.js.coffee to be rendered instead of the edit.haml?
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.haml (0.1ms)
  Rendered software_tags/_form.haml (2.8ms)
  Rendered software_tags/edit.haml (3.2ms)      <---- THIS IS WRONG!
Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 3.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

In my controller, the edit action looks like this:

```
  def edit
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @software_tag }
    end
  end
```

When i try to access json data however, everything is fine from all the environments, so what could be the problem with the wrong output for the js output?

EDIT: Maybe i'm missing something fairly simple. i'm still unable to achieve what is working in development from my production environement. i'm using ruby 1.9.3 with Rails 3.2.6, along with jQuery / jQuery-ujs. Basically, i would refine my question: when making link_to remote: true, how can i force the server to answer me with a javascript file (And branch on the respond_to.js block instead of the html one)?

Comment: The fact that a request is made over AJAX doesn't change what format the request is expecting. An XHR request can still be for an HTML, XML, JSON, GIF or PDF resource.

Comment: i've been messing around with various things, and i really don't understand why the behavior is different from development to production (Only difference is that i'm using passenger on the former). i have tried changing the accept settings of the XHR in jQuery using the ajaxSetup function, still the same issue. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If is gem inside :assets group, this gems are only used for asset directories (in app, vendor, lib), not in views.

There are three methods to works fine:

1. Move coffee-rails outside assets
2. in apllication.rb uncomment this: `# Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)`
3. Use gem coffee-views https://github.com/yury/coffee-views

Comment: Thanks rado. If you would be able to tell me why this behavior is different from development to production, i'd be very happy to accept your answer.

Comment: Because in application.rb you have this:   Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test))) this load group :assets in development, in production is called only in precompile process.

Comment: Note that using coffeescript templates in production performs very badly as the template will get compiled by coffeescript on every request. Consider using js.erb instead.

Answer (score 1):

i have finally found an answer to my question. It sounds like a bug to me, or maybe i'm missing something.

i have put debugging messages on my controller like this:

```
def edit
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { Rails.logger.info "in JS handler" }
    format.html { Rails.logger.info "in HTML handler" }
    format.json { render json: @software_tag }
  end
end
```

In fact, the right actions were called, but the file edit.haml was rendered instead of edit.js.coffe, even when being in the format.js block.

The solution i have found is to move the gem 'coffee-rails' outside the :assets group from my gemfile, like this:
Before:

```
group :assets do
  gem 'uglifier'
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails'
end
```

After:

```
gem 'coffee-rails'
group :assets do
  gem 'uglifier'
  gem 'sass-rails'
end
```

Now, everything is working as expected on the production environment.

Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried:

```
respond_to :js, :only => :edit
```

At the top of your controller?

Or specifying the template rendering in the format.js block the same way you're doing with the json block.